# Using -Credential with Copy-Item failure

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy a file to a UNC filename where my user has permission, but no traditional drive letter mapping. `PSVersion 5.0.10586.11`

```
# Get and store the password in an encrypted file. Do this once only.
# (Get-Credential).Password | ConvertFrom-SecureString | Out-File .\my_secret.txt"

$user = "me"
$file = ".\my_secret.txt"
$cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential `
 -ArgumentList $user, (Get-Content $file | ConvertTo-SecureString)

Copy-Item -Credential $cred .\list.txt "\\zeplin.nowhere.org\data\docs\log"
```

Running the script seems to suggest that `Copy-Item` does not support `-Credential`. I would rather not create a new drive letter mapping with `New-PSDrive` unless I must. Using `Get-Help Copy-Item` shows that it supports the `-Credentials` parameter. The following error message is returned.

```
The FileSystem provider supports credentials only on the New-PSDrive cmdlet. Perform the operation again without specifying
credentials.
PS C:\Users\me> .\t.ps1
At C:\Users\me\t.ps1:8 char:1
+ Copy-Item -Credential $cred .\list.txt "\\zeplin.nowhere.org\data\docs ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotImplemented: (:) [], PSNotSupportedException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NotSupported
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copy-Item has a Credential parameter for PS providers that support it. The FileSystem provider, as indicated, does not. You'll have to use New-psdrive.